# No se encontró el proveedor especificado El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0'

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, oledb

Tengo un proyecto en excel 2013 y estaba usando El proveedor 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0' para conectarme a una base de datos access 2013, el día de hoy me realizaron un cambio de versión de office a 365 y ya no funciona mi proyecto, el error que sale es " No se encontró el proveedor especificado ".

No se cual proveedor debo usar, alguien puede indicarme.

Comment: encontre que puedo usar el proveedor   Microsoft OLE DB Service Component 1.0 Type Library, lo intento usar con la cadena de conexion que tenia y me sale un error en el metodo open del objeto "_connecction"                   Esta es mi cadena de conexion                                                                     
 Set con = New ADODB.connection
    con.Open ("Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;" & "Data Source=" & path & NombreBase & ".accdb;")

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/